# Get window height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

window height is getting the length of the html document rather than the size of my browser window.

Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            alert($( window ).height());
    });
```

I also have at the top of my doc which I've read can cause issues:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: You need `clientHeight`

Comment: [A tale of two viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) at Quirksmode.org is a good read.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Great link, but the OP understands those concepts, `jQuery.height()` is supposed to correctly get the height of browser window, not the HTML document.

Comment: fyi, incorrect statement in user's question regarding window height: window height is not getting the length of the html document. A document can be larger than its window.

Comment: Even though the answer below is correct, I feel as if OP wanted the size of the whole document. If that also fits your needs, you need to use `document.body.clientHeight` (as recommended by @marekful) if you want to calculate the height of the whole document.

Answer (score 16):

window.innerHeight

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert(window.innerHeight);
});
```

Comment: Why can't I use $( window ).height()

Comment: You should be able to do both. Open the console inside your browser, and test. Right click inside broswer => "Inspect element" => "Console" tab. Also "window.innerHeight" is plain javascript.

Answer (score -1):

I think it must be an old version of jQuery that is buggy? Using 1.6.4 (the oldest that jsfiddle supports), I get the right behavior. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SawXY/1/)

If you can't figure it out, you can use `window.innerHeight`, I try to use jQuery only if it takes less code, which it doesn't in this case.

```
div {
  height: 2000px;
}
// onload
alert($(window).height());
// outputs window height, not 2000
```

Comment: must be something else in my code causing this. I changed jquery to 1.6.4. Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: @panthro No, but if you can give us a link that reproduces the problem, we can take a look. The fiddle I showed is using `<!DOCTYPE html>` so that's not the problem

Comment: @panthro Are you sure your doctype declaration is the very first thing on the HTML source? Also, try the latest version of jQuery and see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-dev/AYhPpu0wj0A

Comment: Good Advice: "I try to use jQuery only if it takes less code, which it doesn't in this case." I believe this will allow for less processing and better performance in larger applications.

Comment: @DonaldPowell Less code doesn't mean better performance or less processing. Often jQuery has to do more work to cover cases you may not care about. When I say, I use jQuery when it's less code, that's only when talking about code in non-critical sections of the app. For critical sections, you have to benchmark